# Unable to Authorize Salesforce through Workbench

Tags: soql, workbench

When I tried to validate salesforce via Workbench (https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php), It is throwing me a weird Error : "An error has occurred and you have been logged out:
Unknown OAuth Error. Status Code: 503"[image: Unknown OAuth Error]

Please let me know if someone else has faced this issue before and has any idea how resolve it.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just try again. Might be a temporary glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Just try again. Might be a temporary glitch.

If it doesnt work then try removing/revoking `Workbench` from your User Setting, and click revoke workbench and other non used Ouath Connected apps.

[image]

Then try to do the same process again and check if this helps.

If you are behind a corporate proxy then host your own version of Workbench, in heroku, and then use that. Steps in [Github](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench)

Comment: Hi Nagendra, Thanks for the response. I'm able to login and validate with Production but it is throwing the same error for all sandboxes.

Comment: Ok, then can you check in one of the sandboxes and try to revoke it from oauth connected app as shown above,

Comment: Hi Nagendra, I think it was a technical glitch. After trying few more times, now I'm able to login with the sandbox which i needed. I did not not revoke in the OAuth connected app but still did work. Thanks for your time and help. Have a nice day.